# How can I deploy a smart contract to RSK without using Truffle?

Tags: rpc, truffle, rsk

After compiling a Solidity file using `solc`, how can I deploy the output bytecode as a smart contract to RSK?
I know how to do this using Truffle already, but what alternatives are there available for this task?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

RSK is (mostly) compatible with Ethereum.
In particular, for dev tools,
it has JSON-RPC compatibility plus VM compatibility.
So if you are a Ethereum developer,
you can use tools/ libs that you are familiar with.
Here are several methods, apart from Truffle:

- [using Geth console and Remix](https://developers.rsk.co/tutorials/ethereum-devs/geth-attach-deploy-smart-contract/), or
- [using Metamask/Nifty and Remix](https://developers.rsk.co/tutorials/ethereum-devs/remix-and-metamask-with-rsk-testnet/), or
- using MyCrypto or [MyEtherWallet](https://www.myetherwallet.com/interface/deploy-contract)
  contract deploy tools (if you have the contract bytecode).

If you want to do this **manually**,
you can do so using the terminal by
sending a transaction using `curl`
via JSON-RPC like this:

```
curl \
  -X POST \
  -H "Content-Type:application/json" \
  --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_sendTransaction","params":[{"from":"FROM_ADDRESS","to":"0x00","gasPrice":"0x3938700","gas":"0x67C28", "data":"SIGNED_CONTRACT_DEPLOYMENT_BYTECODE"}],"id":1}' \
  http://localhost:4444
```

- Use the `eth_estimateGas` RPC to obtain the value of `gas`.
- Use the `eth_gasPrice` RPC to obtain the value of `gasPrice`.

Note that the above command assumes that you have RSKj running on `localhost`.

Also note that just like any other transaction
which modifies the state of the blockchain,
you will need to sign the deployment transaction as well,
in order to produce `SIGNED_CONTRACT_DEPLOYMENT_BYTECODE`.
You can use the `eth_sign` RPC for this,
or the equivalent method in your wallet.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is good to know what happen in these situations. Short answer: you send a transaction, to field is empty, data field containts the bytecode of the compiled contract CONCATENATED with the ABI encoded arguments for constructor, if any

Usually, I write my own utilities (in NodeJS, to be cross platform), to interact with an Ethereum/RSK node. You can explore the code of the implemention of client.deploy in my personal project https://github.com/ajlopez/rskapi

Also, you can check the implementation of my command line tools (based on the above library) https://github.com/ajlopez/rskclitools#deploy-a-contract

An code example in https://github.com/ajlopez/EthFaucet/tree/master/commands (see execute setup)

I will add the feature to provide directly the bytecode to deploy command, and in a few days, I will write a post with a bit more organized description

Comment: awesome! `client.deploy` sounds like a good option to try!